# Jquery function only running after 2 clicks

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile

I have a jquery function that opens the menu for mobile browsers.  It opens, but only does it after it is clicked twice.  I am using jquery mobile, so I have changed my;

`$(document).ready(function(){`

to read

`$(document).on('pageinit', function(){`

The function in question is;

```
    function showMobileDrop(){
    $('.mobileDrop').show("slide", {direction:"up"}, 1000);
    }
    $(function(){
    $('.cMenu').click(showMobileDrop);
    });
```

This interacts with this menu on my page.  The mobile menu is hidden unless the page is under 700px wide;

```
    <div class="mobileMenu">
    <a href="#" class="cMenu">Menu<img src="images/icons/menu.png"></a>
    <ul class="mobileDrop">
        <a href="#closeMenu"><li>Close</li></a>
        <li><a href="#index">HOME</a></li>
        <li><a href="#classical">CLASSICAL</a></li>
        <li><a href="#weddings">WEDDINGS</a></li>
        <li><a href="#events">EVENTS</a></li>
        <li><a href="#americana">AMERICANA</a></li>
        <li><a href="#instruction">INSTRUCTION</a></li>
    </ul>
   </div>
```

So as I said it works, but only if the anchor link class="cMenu" is clicked twice. Not sure if I should be using pagechange, or something different.  I am basically trying to write the effects I added in so they will work just as they would in a normal document ready environmment but allow them to function in the jquery mobile multipage model.

Comment: Does it happen on first page too?

Comment: is there some `:hover` css on the `a` as well? Rhis might be worth reading: http://www.prowebdesign.ro/how-to-deal-with-hover-on-touch-screen-devices/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the element being clicked is an `<a>`, you should prevent default behavior (following the link to #), which might be interfering with you function.

Something like this:

```
function showMobileDrop(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $('.mobileDrop').show("slide", {direction:"up"}, 1000);
}
$(function() {
    $('.cMenu').click(showMobileDrop);
});
```